# Magento2 Form Component Base Table not found

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, forms, uicomponent

I'm creating an input form for my module with form components as recommended by the magento2 documentation.

The uiComponent is displaying on the page however it's throwing this error - where it's showing the namespace for the model rather than the table name.

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'site.Vendor\Module\Model\Slideshow' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `Vendor\Module\Model\Slideshow` AS `main_table` WHERE (`id` = '')

I'm not entirely sure what's the cause of this - or where it's getting the namespace from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused by using the namespace as the first argument in `_init`, for the resource model.

This is because it's injected into the `uiComponent` via `di.xml`

Instead use the table name - like below;

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel;

class Slideshow extends 
\Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('vendor_module_slideshow', 'id');
    }
}
```